# Can I deflect enemy grenades?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I do anything about a grenade in Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54019/can-i-do-anything-about-a-grenade-in-mass-effect-3)

In single player "Insanity" difficulty, Cerberus agents throw grenades with pinpoint accuracy all the time. Due to the deadlyness of grenades of this difficulty, it always forces me out of cover and into the line of fire of the enemy.

What can I do about these grenades other than flee from cover? Is there any biotic option?

Comment: If anything does, shockwave might blow them away

Comment: IIRC, if you are a good marksman, you can shoot them. I think I remember doing this a few times on accident. Though, if you do this, I think it still shows the indicator, they just never blow up.

Comment: If Cerberus trained their soldiers to *cook* the grenades too, they'd have already beaten the Reapers.

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried shockwaving it, but all it did was continue to tick and then blow up in my face. Once a grenade has finished its trajectory, it appears that it becomes a static object. ( I tried throwing a lift grenade and loosed a shock wave while it was bouncing.. nothing happened. )

In regards to your problem, the game normally provides covers that are close to each other- a simple roll to your left or right should solve your cover issues? I do have a sort of invulnerability when I roll, or at least I've never had my shields or health bar drop when I rolled.
Haven't tried timing a roll to dodge the aoe explosion of a nade though....

I've also found that if you kill an enemy before he throws the damn nade ( whilst he's in the throwing position ) he drops the nade. His comrades don't die from it though.